# Add an image to a plotly express figure

Tags: python, plotly, dashboard, plotly-dash

I'm new to plotly/plotly express and i'm having a really hard time finding any working example other than the documentation examples for the library (which are really basic and standard).

I have, let's say a scatter plot, in plotly express:

```
fig = px.scatter(any_random_data)
```

And i want to add to that plot an image in a fixed (x,y) position, but i don't know (and can't find!) if there is any kind of method for that.

I've seen there is an `add_trace()` method to add traces to the plot (i guess), is there any similar function for adding images? (Like `add_image()` or something)

Comment: Take a look at this page (https://plotly.com/python/images/) which discusses this

Comment: That's exactly what i was looking for, thanks a lot! Edit: Worked perfect! Thanks again :)